# Blank screen after login

Tags: login, pulseaudio, alsa, output

I think I know how I got here. I was trying to get audio working and issued the command

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
```

It seemed like it was removing a lot of packages

I did reinstall but when I rebooted I get the blank screen after login. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the same thing however I looked all over couldn't find an answer anywhere so I decided to investigate myself as I didn't want to reinstall the OS and lose all my files.

I investigated the `/var/log/apt/history.log` and found that the command you and I ran uninstalled a few key packages namely `cinnamon` for me or if your using GNOME it will be that. So to fix the issue I re-installed the missing files.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> will drop you from the blank screen into a terminal login with your normal user account and install the missing file with:

(If you're not using cinnamon just take a look in the above log file and see what the command uninstalled for you and reinstall them)

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio cinnamon-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11 mint-meta-cinnamon cinnamon alsa-base cinnamon-control-center pulseaudio-module-bluetooth libcanberra-pulse
```

Now reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

I know this is a bit of a late reply but hopefully it will help other people who run into this issue.